# Delete a calendar entry on ipad programatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a requrirement in my iPad app development where I have to delete a calendar entry on a press of a button. I know to create a calendar entry with EKEventStore. How do I delete. A pseudo code would be of great help. 
**I create the entry with the pseudo code below:**

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = @"EVENT TITLE";
event.notes     = @"Event notes here";
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use :

```
- (BOOL)removeEvent:(EKEvent *)event span:(EKSpan)span error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: How do i get the current calendar entry?

Comment: To get the current entry, you must specify `EKSpan` to `EKSpanThisEvent`

Answer (score 0):

```
EKEventStore *storeDelete=[[EKEventStore alloc]init];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSString *uid=  [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueIdentifier"];

        EKEvent *eventDelete=[storeDelete eventWithIdentifier:uid];

        [storeDelete removeEvent:eventDelete span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:nil];
```

create an object for EKEventStore if you are deleting in other class. For deleting an event you need to have the unique identifier of an event(get identifier by calling event.eventIdentifier after saving the event).

```
[storeDelete removeEvent:eventDelete span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:nil];
```

used to remove particular event with event id.

`EKSpanThisEvent`  is used to this only this event and and `EKSpanFutureEvents` is used to delete all the events associated with this event id.